# Accesssing cookies of another domain using Iframes and Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, crossdomain

Using Iframe we can embed webpages of another domain provided the **X-Frame-Options** isn't set to **SAMEORIGIN**. This also loads the cookie inside the iframe.
Now, one can access this cookie if it's in the **iframe** box using **document.cookie**. I wanted to ask if it's possible to send this cookie by mailing this to oneself (by writing a script inside the iframe tag).

**My Opinion:**
This is possible if we can write the **script** tag inside the **iframe** tag in the web-page. But it doesn't seem to work in my case.

We can also insert a **script** dynamically inside the **iframe**. I wanted to know if it's possible or not.

I think it might not work since the iframe loaded might overwrite all the content inside the **iframe** tag and the script tag might not work.
If this is the case then why there is a **iframe** closing tag at all. Can't it be only: **iframe src="https://abc.def.com"** tag to define iframes?

Comment: Have you looked at Window.postMessage() in HTML5?

Comment: The question is answered below by Steffen Ullrich. Have a look at it @Simply G.

Comment: I agree with the principle and his answer, but there are several technologies to 'safely enables cross-origin communication'. Both old and new. You can share information from the cookie between iframe and hosting page using scripting. I must add that I am not saying it is a good thing to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same Origin Policy ensures that you cannot read or modify the content of a page with different origin. In case of the iframe this means that the parent frame can fully replace the iframe (and thus changing the origin) but it cannot read or modify the contents of the iframe has a different origin.

Thus reading a cookie cross-origin from an iframe will only work if the content of the iframe explicitly communicates with the parent frame (like with postMessage) to share the cookie value. Usually this is not the case with unrelated origins but if you find a XSS attack at the iframes origin then you might be able to trick the iframe into sending this cookie to the parent frame.

Note that X-Frame-Options is unrelated to the same origin policy. It is only used to define if a site can be put into an iframe or not. This is important to defend against [Clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) or other UI-Redressing attacks.

Comment: Does that mean that we cannot modify the content of the iframe or play around with it's elements from the main-page's DOM ?

Comment: @aka_007: you cannot read or modify content cross-origin. This includes iframes.

Comment: Makes sense since Cross Domain access is prevented in browsers. 
I will wait for some other answers before marking it accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich your wikipedia link points to german version. You might want to change it to english one just in case.